# Listview header customization in WPF - Align content to edges

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a Listview in WPF with a header for each column that displays some text. I want to customize the header and add a button next to the text. This I know to achieve. 
What I cannot figure out is how to place the button in such a way that it is always right aligned, even when the window containing the list view expands.

Has anyone done this or can anyone help me understand how to do this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [DockPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.aspx) for this

As an example in my project:

```
<DockPanel Width="Auto" 
               Height="Auto" 
               LastChildFill="True">

    <!-- Other docked elements -->

    <UniformGrid Width="300" 
                     Background="White"
                     Margin="0,0,0,0"
                     DockPanel.Dock="Right">

            <!-- Elements in the UniformGrid -->

    </UniformGrid>

    <!-- Other docked elements -->

<DockPanel/>
```

This part: `DockPanel.Dock="Right"` will make the element (in my case a UniformGrid) be fixed onto the right of the DockPanel